# PHP fetch_assoc() results not as expected from database, loop not working, int conversion?

Tags: php, json

Data from my query looks like this:

```
T             t0 t1 t2 t3 
1390716665000 137 47 82 
1390717359000 105 47 79 
1390718399000 126 46 79
```

my php code looks like this:

```
    $i=0;
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $RowTime = (int)$row['T'];
    $data['t0'][$i] = array($RowTime, (int)$row['t0']);
    $data['t1'][$i] = array($RowTime, (int)$row['t1']);
    $data['t2'][$i] = array($RowTime, (int)$row['t2']);
    $data['t3'][$i] = array($RowTime, (int)$row['t3']);
    $i++;
};
```

and my json looks like this:

```
{"t0":[[2147483647,137],[2147483647,105],[2147483647,126],...
 "t1":[[2147483647,47],[2147483647,47],[2147483647,46],...
 "t2":[[2147483647,82],[2147483647,79],[2147483647,79],...
```

What in the wide wide world of sports am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: what json object structure do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2147483647 is the maximum value for int, so the conversion is stopping at that. Use float instead.